# Computing 4-digit float point arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Compute $f(π)$ using 4-digit float point arithmetic if $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 8 - \sqrt{x} }$

Is my $x = 3.141$? and is $f(x) = 0.306$?

Comment: $$ x\approx 0.l3059319222\approx 0.306$$

Answer (score 2):

If you use your 4-digit float point arithmetic for every step you get (assuming correct rounding to nearest):
$$x = 3.142$$
$$\sqrt{3.142} = 1.773$$
$$3.142^2 = 9.872$$
$$9.872-8 = 1.872$$
$$1.872-1.773 = 0.099$$
$$f(x) =\sqrt{0.099} = 0.3146$$
Note the lost of a digit through cancellation in the penultimate step.